# Symfony 2 : Class "Entity\ClientClass" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

Im working with Symfony 2.4 im getting this exception when i came to run the code

```
doctrine:generate:entities
Class "Entity\ClientClass" is not a valid entity or mapped super class
```

How to resolve it.

Here is the code in Entity

```
namespace category\CategoryBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * category
 */
class category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show code of your entity

Answer (score 1):

We can't help you without details : 
- check the namespace of the Entity/ClientClass and the file path according to doctrine configuration, by default : src/BundleName/Entity

- does your class have the annotation @ORM\Entity or @ORM\MappedSuperClass ?